# CSV import with Python; incorrect "," delimiter behavior

Tags: python, csv

I am using the csv module in the following manner

```
header = '"Id","IsDeleted","MasterRecordId","Salutation","FirstName","LastName","Name","Type","RecordTypeId","ParentId","BillingStreet","BillingCity","BillingState","BillingPostalCode","BillingCountry","BillingLatitude"'
header_c = csv.reader(header, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

names = []
for row in header_c:
  names.append(row)
```

Inspecting names returns:

```
[['Id'], ['', ''], ['IsDeleted'], ['', ''], ['MasterRecordId'], ['', ''], ['Salutation'], ['', ''], ['FirstName'], ['', ''], ['LastName'], ['', ''], ['Name'], ['', ''], ['Type'], ['', ''], ['RecordTypeId'], ['', ''], ['ParentId'], ['', ''], ['BillingStreet'], ['', ''], ['BillingCity'], ['', ''], ['BillingState'], ['', ''], ['BillingPostalCode'], ['', ''], ['BillingCountry'], ['', ''], ['BillingLatitude']]
```

I could ignore all the odd entries, keeping 0, 2, 4, ...., but I don't understand what I am doing wrong and why 
the commas are being kept as entries. What do I have to change in order for the comma's to be dropped. 'IsDeleted' should be the second entry (names[1])

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csv.reader()` can handle any *iterable*, and expects each iteration over that iterable to yield a *complete line*. The iterable can be a file-like object, or (normally) a *list* of strings:

```
header_c = csv.reader([header], delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

If you pass in *just* a single string object, the string itself is iterated over as if each character was a line, but because of the quotes `csv` will continue to read 'lines' until it finds a closing quote character.

The next 'line' contains *just* a comma, so that is seen as a line of *two* empty values.

Or, to take the first 5 characters (`"Id",`) as an example, `csv` does this:

- Iterate and receive `"`. This is a quoted value, so include everything up to the end of the line.
- There is an opening quote, iterate until a closing quote is found, everything until that point is appended to the existing value.

  - loop and receive `I`, append.
  - loop and receive `d`, append.
  - loop and receive `"`. Quote closed, yield a complete row `['Id']`.
- Iterate and receive `,`. This is a complete line with a delimiter, so yield `['', '']`.

Whenever I need to pass in a string value to `csv.reader()` I use [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines); this method will *always* return a list, so this works for lines without newlines too:

```
header_c = csv.reader(header.splitlines(True), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

I leave in the newlines (pass in `True` to `str.splitlines()`; quoted values with newlines are then properly returned with the newlines included.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass a file-like object (or any other iterable) to [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) as a first parameter.

> csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
>
> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator
>   protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called —
>   file objects and list objects are both suitable.

One option is to read the string into the `StringIO` buffer:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
header_c = csv.reader(StringIO(header), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

Then, in names, you'll get:

```
[['Id', 'IsDeleted', 'MasterRecordId', 'Salutation', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Name', 'Type', 'RecordTypeId', 'ParentId', 'BillingStreet', 'BillingCity', 'BillingState', 'BillingPostalCode', 'BillingCountry', 'BillingLatitude']]
```

Comment: That did it. Any comments on what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: `header_c = csv.reader([header], delimiter=',', quotechar='"')` also works.

Comment: @artdv please see Martinj's answer. He has explained the whole story very well.